# How to update all rows to truncate milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a lookup table where one of the columns contains each date between 2000 and 2030.

Problem is that the generated dates here all have milliseconds at the end, eg:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-02 00:00:00.000
2000-01-03 00:00:00.000
2000-01-04 00:00:00.000
```

My other datetime columns in my data don't have this, e.g.:

```
2011-05-17 13:11:11
2011-05-18 09:39:17
2011-06-15 10:54:09
2011-06-20 10:16:43
```

[image: http://s15.postimg.org/5jw1q6y2z/2014_03_14_09_47_48_Microsoft_SQL_Server_Managem.png]

I think this may be causing an issue when aggregating up to Month using a BI tool, so I wanted to update all rows in the Calendar_Date column (in the lookup table), to truncate milliseconds off all rows. Could someone provide guidance on how I can do this?

Structures of both columns:
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: they do, you're just not looking at them, have a look and it might expose the root of your problem. All `DateTime` columns have milliseconds. How are you aggreating, grouping by the datetime column? Try grouping by `date(<datetime column>)`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? A select query on my data column gives this: http://s15.postimg.org/5jw1q6y2z/2014_03_14_09_47_48_Microsoft_SQL_Server_Managem.png

Comment: The same query in on the lookup table's date column gives milliseconds, since the data there has that

Comment: Are your other datetime columns smalldatetime ? Regular datetime is to the fraction

Comment: I can't see your link, you'll have to add detail to the question.

Comment: Well, maybe this helps. I think this is why the following query from the BI tool fails:

Comment: select a12.Calendar_Year  Calendar_Year,
 a11.dt  datetime,
 (sum(a11.mc_gross) - sum(a11.mc_fee))  WJXBFS1
from shine_orders a11
 join Calendar a12
   on  (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a11.dt, 101)) = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a12.Calendar_Date, 101)) and 
 a11.dt = a12.Calendar_Date)
group by a12.Calendar_Year,
 a11.dt

Comment: @Jodrell, I've added the image in the description. Just uploading pics of the column structure, both are datetime.

Comment: If you wanna update the lookup_table use this `substring (Dat,0,len(Dat) - 3)` in the update statement

Comment: You are converting the datetime to a `varchar(10)` and thus chopping the time portion off the end.

Comment: @G one, Thanks, doesn't quite work unfortunately: Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: @Jodrell So you think that the differences in the data stored shouldn't be the issue here?

Comment: @loco - Be aware that datetimes are not stored as strings.  It's like thinking that the float "123.456" actually looks like that in memory.  The DATETIME data-type is capable of represent fractions of a second, no matter what you do, that's going to be true.  You'll need to change data-types to change what is stored.  BUT what you are seeing is a difference when converting that binary data-type in to a string.  I'm 99% sure you're going down a rabbit hole here, having mis-diagnosed the problem.

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to eliminate all differences to try and pin down why the above query from the engine returns no results. This was a key difference between dates in my data, and dates in the lookup table.

Comment: @loco - I would suggest changing your query to NOT use the convoluted convert structure in your join.  If they are both DATETIMEs then the join just needs to be `data.datetime >= calendar.date AND data.datetime < calendar.date + 1`, and you should also be grouping by `calendar.date` rather than `data.datetime` if you want daily results.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I've found the root cause. I noticed in my previous project, in my lookup table all dates where in date datatype, not datetime. I altered the column datatype to date in this project, and the new SQL seems to be aggregating correctly (casting dt column to Date in the expression, to make it match; warehouse should not be altered). Thanks again!

Comment: @loco - Casting to a date in the query means that the optimiser won't be able to use any indexes on that fields.  As a general rule, if you are searching a field, don't put it in a function.  *(Search for `SARGable` for more information.)*

Comment: You're right, there's an underlying problem elsewhere that's making this worse. I need to investigate more :( thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table
set Calendar_Date=convert(datetime,(convert(date,Calendar_Date)))
```

Comment: Setting yours as the answer, since a derivative of your update query led me to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have mis-disagnosed the problem, it's not the data, it appears to be the SQL.

Let me show you some issues with your query.

```
SELECT
  a12.Calendar_Year   AS Calendar_Year,
  a11.dt              AS datetime,
  (sum(a11.mc_gross) - sum(a11.mc_fee))   AS WJXBFS1
FROM
  shine_orders   AS a11
JOIN
  Calendar       AS a12
    ON (  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a11.dt,            101))
        = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a12.Calendar_Date, 101))
        AND a11.dt = a12.Calendar_Date
       )
GROUP BY
  a12.Calendar_Year,
  a11.dt
```

That's your query slightly differently laid out so that I can identify individual pieces.

Let's look at the JOIN first...

```
ON (  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a11.dt,            101))
    = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a12.Calendar_Date, 101))
```

This does indeed compare date parts only.  It converts both values to strings of the format `'mm/dd/yyyy'` and then compares them.  It's not considered the most efficient way of doing it, but it *does* work.

```
    AND a11.dt = a12.Calendar_Date
```

This seems to be a rogue condition.  This compares values that include a time, to values that don't.  this will be preventing your join from working.

Now let's look at the SELECT and the GROUP BY

```
SELECT
  a12.Calendar_Year   AS Calendar_Year,
  a11.dt              AS datetime,
```

and

```
GROUP BY
  a12.Calendar_Year,
  a11.dt
```

`a11.dt`, is actually the value from the data, not the calendar table.  This means that you're not grouping by day, you're grouping by `the exact day and time` that exists in the data.

I would recommend the following query instead.

```
SELECT
  a12.Calendar_Year   AS Calendar_Year,
  a12.Calendar_Date   AS Calendar_Date,
  (sum(a11.mc_gross) - sum(a11.mc_fee))   AS WJXBFS1
FROM
  Calendar       AS a12
LEFT JOIN
  shine_orders   AS a11
    ON  a11.dt >= a12.Calendar_Date
    AND a11.dt <  a12.Calendar_Date + 1
WHERE
      a12.Calendar_Date >= '2013-01-01'
  AND a12.Calendar_Date <  '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY
  a12.Calendar_Year,
  a12.Calendar_Date
```

***EDIT:***  I originally missed out a `+ 1` in the final query.

Answer (score 0):

When you say DATETIME data type it means sql server will store the values as two binary numbers; one representing the number of days (the date) and the other representing the number of ticks (the time) and the data is presented as  `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000'`.  If it is stored in any other way other then this it is not datetime.

To store datetime values in your required format which is `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` you will need to store them as string as varchar values.

But the question is ? is it really worth it ?  And the answer is NOOOOOO...

Reasons

1) If you want to present data in `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` format you can always do this at rumtime, writing queries which will present the data in this format.

2) If you have saved your values as string you will need to cast them as datetime before you could use any of the datetime functions.

3) Since these will be only string not datetime if you do not have proper constraint user can add false data such as 2013-15-15. and sql server will accept it as a valid string.

and the list goes on.  thats why I would suggest to keep the extra zeros and dont worry abot them.

**UPDATE**

Your Current column could be in [`SMALLDATETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) Datatype be not in Datetime.

Try this....

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(Col1 SMALLDATETIME, Col2 DATETIME)
GO

INSERT INTO Test_Table
VALUES 
(GETDATE()-1,GETDATE()-1),(GETDATE()-2,GETDATE()-2),(GETDATE()-3,GETDATE()-3)

SELECT * FROM Test_Table
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║        Col1         ║          Col2           ║
╠═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 2014-03-13 10:16:00 ║ 2014-03-13 10:15:58.483 ║
║ 2014-03-12 10:16:00 ║ 2014-03-12 10:15:58.483 ║
║ 2014-03-11 10:16:00 ║ 2014-03-11 10:15:58.483 ║
╚═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: That makes me wonder then, if DATETIME should always be stored as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000', it shouldn't make sense that my dt column can store as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', right? Because that's how the data is there at the moment.

Comment: DATETIMES are not stored as a string of ANY format.  They are stored as two binary numbers; one representing the number of days (the date) and the other representing the number of ticks (the time).  Conceiving a DATETIME to be `stored as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000'` is completely incorrect.  The formats you refer to ONLY become use when converting from a binary (internal) value to a string (for representing on a screen).

Comment: Thanks for educating me thats why I love this platform you always learn something new. I thought the data itself was stored in this format. Anyway Cheers mate :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
SELECT
    a12.Calendar_Year Calendar_Year,
    (sum(a11.mc_gross) - sum(a11.mc_fee)) WJXBFS1
FROM shine_orders a11
JOIN Calendar a12
    ON CONVERT(date, a11.dt) = CONVERT(date, a12.Calendar_Date)
GROUP BY a12.Calendar_Year
```

---

If `Calendar_Year` is just how it sounds, a calendar year, you could do

```
SELECT
    Year(a11.dt) Calendar_Year,
    (sum(a11.mc_gross) - sum(a11.mc_fee)) WJXBFS1
FROM shine_orders a11
GROUP BY Year(a11.dt)
```

Comment: The use of CONVERT prevents the use of indexes.  I would suggest `ON a11.dt >= a12.calendar_date AND a11.dt < DATEADD(DAY, 1, a12.calendar_date) GROUP BY a12.calendar_year, a12.calendar_date` to maintain the ability to use indexes on `a11`.

Comment: @MatBailie totally agree, but if performance is the issue, I doubt the join to Calendar is even necessary.

Comment: It is if a) you want results for dates that have no data b) you need something from the calendar table, such as "is_bankholday", or the calendar year is based on something financial (such as starting from the first monday in the year).

Comment: Basically what the BI engine is supposed to be doing, is aggregating my data at the Date level, to the Year level. This is for the Calendar lookup table is for. But I find as soon as I try and add any other level, such as Year or Month, the aggregation gives no results. Somewhere, the query from the engine is eliminating all data.

Comment: @loco, assuming `Calendar.Calendar_Year` hold something other than the standard year part of the date, you can group your data by `Calendar_Year` like this.